# Prevent automatic title on resave

Tags: localization, titles

I have a situation where I wish to automatically set entry title based on locale entry was created in. This is what I use for title:

`{{ object.locale == "jp" ? "Japanese title" : "English title"}}`

This works fine but when I create an entry in Japanese locale and open it in English locale and resave it the title changes to "English title" and that's not what I want, I wish to preserve the original title. Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely untested, but something like this should work:

```
{{ !object.id ? (object.locale == "jp" ? "Japanese title" : "English title") : object.title) }}
```

Basically only run your logic if the entry doesn't have an ID yet (which new entries won't until they are saved).

Comment: Thanks to your help this is what worked:

```{{ object.title ? object.title : (object.locale == "jp" ? "Japanese title" : "English title ") }}```